# dockerhub specify latest tag

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a [dockerhub repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo) where I periodically pull my images, when I need to pull them I noticed that if I specify the version tag:

```
docker pull cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:0.2
```

everything works fine, but if I try the version-less command it tells me that `latest` is not specified:

```
docker pull cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo

### response
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

I tried to google around, to look at [Docker-Manifest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/), here etc. but couldn't find a way to understand how do I tell Dockerhub which image must be considered `latest`. Does anybody know how? Do I need to create an image tagged as `latest` and replace it every time I update the image?

Comment: It is absolutely not mandatory for an image in a registry to provide a `latest` tag. Note that technically speaking, it's not really a "tag". It is supposed to point to the "most recent" (this def can highly vary between image maintainers....) version of the image. If you don't provide a tag to the docker client when pulling the image, it will automatically happend by default the `latest` tag to the image. If the image maintainer did not provide one, you will get the above error, exactly as if you had typed `docker pull cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the tag, and `build` your image as

```
docker build -t cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo .
```

This way it's going to automatically tag it as the `latest`, you need one little extra step if you want to "version" your image, by `tagging` it with the actual version

```
docker tag cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:0.2
```

Then you can `push` both to your docker hub repository

```
docker push cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo

docker push cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:0.2
```

So you can `pull` a specific version, or just omit the version and `pull` the `latest`

**Latest**:

```
docker pull cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo
```

**Version 0.2**:

```
docker pull cccnrc/diagnosticator-asilo:0.2
```

Of course, you have to do this every time you `build` a new version


*You can also choose not to version your images or `push` only the latest without the version number... but that's up to you*